# Getting Fluent NHibernate to work with SQLite

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, system.data.sqlite

I'm sure there is something simple I've not done but I'm trying to get Fluent NHibernate to work with Sqlite on my machine.

I used NuGet to download fluent nhibernate and added the following entity and mapping:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap ()
        {
        Id(x => x.CustomerCode);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Table("tblCustomer");
        }
}
```

Then following the getting started with fluent guide I added the following code to a Windows Command project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                var customer = new Customer { CustomerCode = "123", Name = "Bob" };
                session.SaveOrUpdate(customer);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
            SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
            .UsingFile("firstProject.db")
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        // delete the existing db on each run
        if (File.Exists("firstProject.db"))
            File.Delete("firstProject.db");

        // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
        // and exports a database schema from it
        new SchemaExport(config)
          .Create(false, true);
    }
}
```

Finally I added the Sqlite dll using NuGet.. however I'm getting the following error when trying to run the program:

Top Exception:

```
An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
```

Next Exception:

```
Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
```

Inner most exception:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

This is when it's trying to create the session factory.

Can anyone help with this? I'm running a 32 bit machine?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 13):

You need two things:

1. Reference `System.Data.SQLite` in your project.
2. Include `sqlite3.dll`, but you also can’t add reference to sqlite3.dll, because it’s an unmanaged dll. Simply add it as element to solution and set it to copy to output directory.

Comment: Thanks.. seems that when I drop it down to .net 3.5 it works ok.. Targeting .net 4.0 it doesn't work though..

Comment: Look for a example for SQLite .net 4.0 to https://github.com/gergroen/NHibernate-getting-started-guide

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

You need the .NET provider for Sqlite. Download it here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference.. I'll try out the code of a different box to see If that fixes the problem..

Answer (score 5):

After initial investigation I thought it was because my System.Data.SQLite assembly wasn't loaded into memory at the time, so I included code to preload the system.Data.SQLite assembly. However when running the application the real error arose:

Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

to fix this I changed my app.config to look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

with the important bit being **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem today, and spend an hour searching for a solution. Anyway, I found one here:

http://thelongwayback.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/fluent-nhibernate-sqlite-problem-the-idbcommand-and-idbconnection-implementation-in-the-assembly-system-data-sqlite-could-not-be-found/

Basically, you'll have to use an older version of SQLite (v1.0.60) from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/

On another note, I got the same code working yesterday on a machine with VS2010 SP1. The same code wouldn't run today on a machine without SP1. If anyone gets a chance to test this one, i.e., by installing VS2010 SP1, let me know the outcome please.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions, or any else I could find on the Internet, worked for me... until...

I had to install both the x64 and x86 versions of SQLite (per Vadim's link: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), **specifically in that order.**

Initially, I installed the 32-bit before the 64-bit version, which did not fix anything. On a whim, I uninstalled them both and reinstalled them in the opposite order. Now it works!

I've tested this on 2 different machines and verified this was the fix for both of them. Wacky, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.
 
Noticed that the starter sample project targets .net **framework 3.5** and the one I created (exercise project)  is targeting .net **framework 4.0** client profile (default of vs2010).
 
I changed the target version to 3.5 and I was able to work on my exercise project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked to install the System.Data.SqLite via NuGet.

So I opened the "Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager console" and typed:

`Install-Package System.Data.SqLite`